# How to get detail info for issue board using webhooks?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

*Gitlab* has api, which I can use to get an info about [project issue boards](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/boards.html).

But when I use [Gitlab Webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) and [issue events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#issue-events) in particular, I do not receive any data about board where it came from. But the data has an info about "project" and "repo":

```
{
  "object_kind": "issue",
  "event_type": "issue",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Administrator",
  },
  "project": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "testy",
    "description": null,    
  },
```

Is there a way to get data for board from triggered webhook?

I didn't find any info about that.